# Movement in VR with Unity for Oculus Go

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculus, gear-vr, oculusgo

I am trying to build a VR app for Oculus go. I am trying to move OVRPlayerContoller  by pointing at a position on the ground, clicking to set a target position and then your character moves towards it.  The player controller does not move towards the pointed position even tho the object is created on that position.I have written this script for it and attached and attached it to OVRPlayerController.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
public class ClickToMove : MonoBehaviour
{

private Vector3 targetPos; //This Vector3 will store the position where we click to move.

private bool Moving = false; //This bool keeps track of whether we are in the process of moving or not.

private GameObject targetInstance;

//The variables we want to customize. Added info headers to these for the Unity Editor.

[Header("Our Go controller object")]

public GameObject goController;

[Header("Movement Speed")]

public float speed = 1;

[Header("Stop When This Far Away From Target")]

public float haltDistance = 0;

[Header("Optional Target Object")]

public GameObject targetObj;

void Update()

{

    MoveToTarget(); //Here we simply run our MoveToTarget method in the Update method.

    //That way we don't clutter up the Update method with too much code.

}

void MoveToTarget() //Here we do the cluttering instead.

{

    var ray = new Ray(goController.transform.position, goController.transform.forward); //Create a ray going from the goController position and in the Forward direction of the goController.

    RaycastHit hitInfo; //Store info about what the ray hits.

    Physics.Raycast(ray, out hitInfo, 100);

    if (OVRInput.GetUp(OVRInput.Button.PrimaryIndexTrigger)) //If we release the trigger..

    {

        targetPos = hitInfo.point; //Make our targetPos assume the positional value of the hit point.

        if (targetObj) //If we have specified a Target Object to mark where we click.

        //If we didn't, then we don't want to try to instantiate it.

        {

            if (targetInstance) //If there is already a Target Object in the scene.

            {

                Destroy(targetInstance); //Destroy it.

            }

            targetInstance = Instantiate(targetObj, targetPos, transform.rotation); //Create our Target object at the position we clicked.

        }

        Moving = true; //And finally we set Moving to True.

    }

    if (Moving == true) //Since Moving is now true

    {

        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, new Vector3(targetPos.x, transform.position.y, targetPos.z), speed * Time.deltaTime); //Transform our x and z position to move towards the targetPos.

        //Note that our y position is kept at default transform position since we only want to move along the ground plane.

    }

    if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, targetPos) <= haltDistance + 1) //Check proximity to targetPos. Mainly useful to keep your player from setting a target position right next to say a building and then end up clipping through half of it.

    {

        if (targetInstance) //If we created a Target Object..

        {

            Destroy(targetInstance); //Then we want to destroy it when we reach it.

        }

        Moving = false; //Since we have now arrived at our target destination.

    }

}
```

}

I created a cube prefab for the Target Object and Dragged the TrackedRemote Prefab(which contains Go controller model and script) onto the Go Contoller slot.

Then I created a ray from my controller using the script below and attached it to OVRCameraRig.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;
public class VRRaycaster : MonoBehaviour
{

[System.Serializable]
public class Callback : UnityEvent<Ray, RaycastHit> { }

public Transform leftHandAnchor = null;
public Transform rightHandAnchor = null;
public Transform centerEyeAnchor = null;
public LineRenderer lineRenderer = null;
public float maxRayDistance = 500.0f;
public LayerMask excludeLayers;
public VRRaycaster.Callback raycastHitCallback;

void Awake()
{
    if (leftHandAnchor == null)
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("Assign LeftHandAnchor in the inspector!");
        GameObject left = GameObject.Find("LeftHandAnchor");
        if (left != null)
        {
            leftHandAnchor = left.transform;
        }
    }
    if (rightHandAnchor == null)
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("Assign RightHandAnchor in the inspector!");
        GameObject right = GameObject.Find("RightHandAnchor");
        if (right != null)
        {
            rightHandAnchor = right.transform;
        }
    }
    if (centerEyeAnchor == null)
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("Assign CenterEyeAnchor in the inspector!");
        GameObject center = GameObject.Find("CenterEyeAnchor");
        if (center != null)
        {
            centerEyeAnchor = center.transform;
        }
    }
    if (lineRenderer == null)
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("Assign a line renderer in the inspector!");
        lineRenderer = gameObject.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
        lineRenderer.shadowCastingMode = UnityEngine.Rendering.ShadowCastingMode.Off;
        lineRenderer.receiveShadows = false;
        lineRenderer.widthMultiplier = 0.02f;
    }
}

Transform Pointer
{
    get
    {
        OVRInput.Controller controller = OVRInput.GetConnectedControllers();
        if ((controller & OVRInput.Controller.LTrackedRemote) != OVRInput.Controller.None)
        {
            return leftHandAnchor;
        }
        else if ((controller & OVRInput.Controller.RTrackedRemote) != OVRInput.Controller.None)
        {
            return rightHandAnchor;
        }
        // If no controllers are connected, we use ray from the view camera. 
        // This looks super ackward! Should probably fall back to a simple reticle!
        return centerEyeAnchor;
    }
}

void Update()
{
    Transform pointer = Pointer;
    if (pointer == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    Ray laserPointer = new Ray(pointer.position, pointer.forward);

    if (lineRenderer != null)
    {
        lineRenderer.SetPosition(0, laserPointer.origin);
        lineRenderer.SetPosition(1, laserPointer.origin + laserPointer.direction * maxRayDistance);
    }


    RaycastHit hit;
    if (Physics.Raycast(laserPointer, out hit, maxRayDistance, ~excludeLayers))
    {
        if (lineRenderer != null)
        {
            lineRenderer.SetPosition(1, hit.point);
        }

        if (raycastHitCallback != null)
        {
            raycastHitCallback.Invoke(laserPointer, hit);
        }
    }
}
```

}

The problem is that when I press the trigger, the GameObject is created at that point on the floor but the OVRPlayerController does not move towards it.

I have also attached my OVRPlayerController.cs script below:

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

/// <summary>
/// Controls the player's movement in virtual reality.
/// </summary>
[RequireComponent(typeof(CharacterController))]
public class OVRPlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
/// <summary>
/// The rate acceleration during movement.
/// </summary>
public float Acceleration = 0.1f;

/// <summary>
/// The rate of damping on movement.
/// </summary>
public float Damping = 0.3f;

/// <summary>
/// The rate of additional damping when moving sideways or backwards.
/// </summary>
public float BackAndSideDampen = 0.5f;

/// <summary>
/// The force applied to the character when jumping.
/// </summary>
public float JumpForce = 0.3f;

/// <summary>
/// The rate of rotation when using a gamepad.
/// </summary>
public float RotationAmount = 1.5f;

/// <summary>
/// The rate of rotation when using the keyboard.
/// </summary>
public float RotationRatchet = 45.0f;

/// <summary>
/// The player will rotate in fixed steps if Snap Rotation is enabled.
/// </summary>
[Tooltip("The player will rotate in fixed steps if Snap Rotation is enabled.")]
public bool SnapRotation = true;

/// <summary>
/// How many fixed speeds to use with linear movement? 0=linear control
/// </summary>
[Tooltip("How many fixed speeds to use with linear movement? 0=linear control")]
public int FixedSpeedSteps;

/// <summary>
/// If true, reset the initial yaw of the player controller when the Hmd pose is recentered.
/// </summary>
public bool HmdResetsY = true;

/// <summary>
/// If true, tracking data from a child OVRCameraRig will update the direction of movement.
/// </summary>
public bool HmdRotatesY = true;

/// <summary>
/// Modifies the strength of gravity.
/// </summary>
public float GravityModifier = 0.379f;

/// <summary>
/// If true, each OVRPlayerController will use the player's physical height.
/// </summary>
public bool useProfileData = true;

/// <summary>
/// The CameraHeight is the actual height of the HMD and can be used to adjust the height of the character controller, which will affect the
/// ability of the character to move into areas with a low ceiling.
/// </summary>
[NonSerialized]
public float CameraHeight;

/// <summary>
/// This event is raised after the character controller is moved. This is used by the OVRAvatarLocomotion script to keep the avatar transform synchronized
/// with the OVRPlayerController.
/// </summary>
public event Action<Transform> TransformUpdated;

/// <summary>
/// This bool is set to true whenever the player controller has been teleported. It is reset after every frame. Some systems, such as 
/// CharacterCameraConstraint, test this boolean in order to disable logic that moves the character controller immediately 
/// following the teleport.
/// </summary>
[NonSerialized] // This doesn't need to be visible in the inspector.
public bool Teleported;

/// <summary>
/// This event is raised immediately after the camera transform has been updated, but before movement is updated.
/// </summary>
public event Action CameraUpdated;

/// <summary>
/// This event is raised right before the character controller is actually moved in order to provide other systems the opportunity to 
/// move the character controller in response to things other than user input, such as movement of the HMD. See CharacterCameraConstraint.cs
/// for an example of this.
/// </summary>
public event Action PreCharacterMove;

/// <summary>
/// When true, user input will be applied to linear movement. Set this to false whenever the player controller needs to ignore input for
/// linear movement.
/// </summary>
public bool EnableLinearMovement = true;

/// <summary>
/// When true, user input will be applied to rotation. Set this to false whenever the player controller needs to ignore input for rotation.
/// </summary>
public bool EnableRotation = true;

protected CharacterController Controller = null;
protected OVRCameraRig CameraRig = null;

private float MoveScale = 1.0f;
private Vector3 MoveThrottle = Vector3.zero;
private float FallSpeed = 0.0f;
private OVRPose? InitialPose;
public float InitialYRotation { get; private set; }
private float MoveScaleMultiplier = 1.0f;
private float RotationScaleMultiplier = 1.0f;
private bool SkipMouseRotation = true; // It is rare to want to use mouse movement in VR, so ignore the mouse by default.
private bool HaltUpdateMovement = false;
private bool prevHatLeft = false;
private bool prevHatRight = false;
private float SimulationRate = 60f;
private float buttonRotation = 0f;
private bool ReadyToSnapTurn; // Set to true when a snap turn has occurred, code requires one frame of centered thumbstick to enable another snap turn.

void Start()
{
    // Add eye-depth as a camera offset from the player controller
    var p = CameraRig.transform.localPosition;
    p.z = OVRManager.profile.eyeDepth;
    CameraRig.transform.localPosition = p;
}

void Awake()
{
    Controller = gameObject.GetComponent<CharacterController>();

    if (Controller == null)
        Debug.LogWarning("OVRPlayerController: No CharacterController attached.");

    // We use OVRCameraRig to set rotations to cameras,
    // and to be influenced by rotation
    OVRCameraRig[] CameraRigs = gameObject.GetComponentsInChildren<OVRCameraRig>();

    if (CameraRigs.Length == 0)
        Debug.LogWarning("OVRPlayerController: No OVRCameraRig attached.");
    else if (CameraRigs.Length > 1)
        Debug.LogWarning("OVRPlayerController: More then 1 OVRCameraRig attached.");
    else
        CameraRig = CameraRigs[0];

    InitialYRotation = transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y;
}

void OnEnable()
{
    OVRManager.display.RecenteredPose += ResetOrientation;

    if (CameraRig != null)
    {
        CameraRig.UpdatedAnchors += UpdateTransform;
    }
}

void OnDisable()
{
    OVRManager.display.RecenteredPose -= ResetOrientation;

    if (CameraRig != null)
    {
        CameraRig.UpdatedAnchors -= UpdateTransform;
    }
}

void Update()
{
    //Use keys to ratchet rotation
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Q))
        buttonRotation -= RotationRatchet;

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
        buttonRotation += RotationRatchet;
}

protected virtual void UpdateController()
{
    if (useProfileData)
    {
        if (InitialPose == null)
        {
            // Save the initial pose so it can be recovered if useProfileData
            // is turned off later.
            InitialPose = new OVRPose()
            {
                position = CameraRig.transform.localPosition,
                orientation = CameraRig.transform.localRotation
            };
        }

        var p = CameraRig.transform.localPosition;
        if (OVRManager.instance.trackingOriginType == OVRManager.TrackingOrigin.EyeLevel)
        {
            p.y = OVRManager.profile.eyeHeight - (0.5f * Controller.height) + Controller.center.y;
        }
        else if (OVRManager.instance.trackingOriginType == OVRManager.TrackingOrigin.FloorLevel)
        {
            p.y = -(0.5f * Controller.height) + Controller.center.y;
        }
        CameraRig.transform.localPosition = p;
    }
    else if (InitialPose != null)
    {
        // Return to the initial pose if useProfileData was turned off at runtime
        CameraRig.transform.localPosition = InitialPose.Value.position;
        CameraRig.transform.localRotation = InitialPose.Value.orientation;
        InitialPose = null;
    }

    CameraHeight = CameraRig.centerEyeAnchor.localPosition.y;

    if (CameraUpdated != null)
    {
        CameraUpdated();
    }

    UpdateMovement();

    Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.zero;

    float motorDamp = (1.0f + (Damping * SimulationRate * Time.deltaTime));

    MoveThrottle.x /= motorDamp;
    MoveThrottle.y = (MoveThrottle.y > 0.0f) ? (MoveThrottle.y / motorDamp) : MoveThrottle.y;
    MoveThrottle.z /= motorDamp;

    moveDirection += MoveThrottle * SimulationRate * Time.deltaTime;

    // Gravity
    if (Controller.isGrounded && FallSpeed <= 0)
        FallSpeed = ((Physics.gravity.y * (GravityModifier * 0.002f)));
    else
        FallSpeed += ((Physics.gravity.y * (GravityModifier * 0.002f)) * SimulationRate * Time.deltaTime);

    moveDirection.y += FallSpeed * SimulationRate * Time.deltaTime;


    if (Controller.isGrounded && MoveThrottle.y <= transform.lossyScale.y * 0.001f)
    {
        // Offset correction for uneven ground
        float bumpUpOffset = Mathf.Max(Controller.stepOffset, new Vector3(moveDirection.x, 0, moveDirection.z).magnitude);
        moveDirection -= bumpUpOffset * Vector3.up;
    }

    if (PreCharacterMove != null)
    {
        PreCharacterMove();
        Teleported = false;
    }

    Vector3 predictedXZ = Vector3.Scale((Controller.transform.localPosition + moveDirection), new Vector3(1, 0, 1));

    // Move contoller
    Controller.Move(moveDirection);
    Vector3 actualXZ = Vector3.Scale(Controller.transform.localPosition, new Vector3(1, 0, 1));

    if (predictedXZ != actualXZ)
        MoveThrottle += (actualXZ - predictedXZ) / (SimulationRate * Time.deltaTime);
}





public virtual void UpdateMovement()
{
    if (HaltUpdateMovement)
        return;

    if (EnableLinearMovement)
    {
        bool moveForward = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow);
        bool moveLeft = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow);
        bool moveRight = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow);
        bool moveBack = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow);

        bool dpad_move = false;

        if (OVRInput.Get(OVRInput.Button.DpadUp))
        {
            moveForward = true;
            dpad_move = true;

        }

        if (OVRInput.Get(OVRInput.Button.DpadDown))
        {
            moveBack = true;
            dpad_move = true;
        }

        MoveScale = 1.0f;

        if ((moveForward && moveLeft) || (moveForward && moveRight) ||
            (moveBack && moveLeft) || (moveBack && moveRight))
            MoveScale = 0.70710678f;

        // No positional movement if we are in the air
        if (!Controller.isGrounded)
            MoveScale = 0.0f;

        MoveScale *= SimulationRate * Time.deltaTime;

        // Compute this for key movement
        float moveInfluence = Acceleration * 0.1f * MoveScale * MoveScaleMultiplier;

        // Run!
        if (dpad_move || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightShift))
            moveInfluence *= 2.0f;

        Quaternion ort = transform.rotation;
        Vector3 ortEuler = ort.eulerAngles;
        ortEuler.z = ortEuler.x = 0f;
        ort = Quaternion.Euler(ortEuler);

        if (moveForward)
            MoveThrottle += ort * (transform.lossyScale.z * moveInfluence * Vector3.forward);
        if (moveBack)
            MoveThrottle += ort * (transform.lossyScale.z * moveInfluence * BackAndSideDampen * Vector3.back);
        if (moveLeft)
            MoveThrottle += ort * (transform.lossyScale.x * moveInfluence * BackAndSideDampen * Vector3.left);
        if (moveRight)
            MoveThrottle += ort * (transform.lossyScale.x * moveInfluence * BackAndSideDampen * Vector3.right);



        moveInfluence = Acceleration * 0.1f * MoveScale * MoveScaleMultiplier;

#if !UNITY_ANDROID // LeftTrigger not avail on Android game pad
        moveInfluence *= 1.0f + OVRInput.Get(OVRInput.Axis1D.PrimaryIndexTrigger);
#endif

        Vector2 primaryAxis = OVRInput.Get(OVRInput.Axis2D.PrimaryThumbstick);

        // If speed quantization is enabled, adjust the input to the number of fixed speed steps.
        if (FixedSpeedSteps > 0)
        {
            primaryAxis.y = Mathf.Round(primaryAxis.y * FixedSpeedSteps) / FixedSpeedSteps;
            primaryAxis.x = Mathf.Round(primaryAxis.x * FixedSpeedSteps) / FixedSpeedSteps;
        }

        if (primaryAxis.y > 0.0f)
            MoveThrottle += ort * (primaryAxis.y * transform.lossyScale.z * moveInfluence * Vector3.forward);

        if (primaryAxis.y < 0.0f)
            MoveThrottle += ort * (Mathf.Abs(primaryAxis.y) * transform.lossyScale.z * moveInfluence *
                                   BackAndSideDampen * Vector3.back);

        if (primaryAxis.x < 0.0f)
            MoveThrottle += ort * (Mathf.Abs(primaryAxis.x) * transform.lossyScale.x * moveInfluence *
                                   BackAndSideDampen * Vector3.left);

        if (primaryAxis.x > 0.0f)
            MoveThrottle += ort * (primaryAxis.x * transform.lossyScale.x * moveInfluence * BackAndSideDampen *
                                   Vector3.right);
    }

    if (EnableRotation)
    {
        Vector3 euler = transform.rotation.eulerAngles;
        float rotateInfluence = SimulationRate * Time.deltaTime * RotationAmount * RotationScaleMultiplier;

        bool curHatLeft = OVRInput.Get(OVRInput.Button.PrimaryShoulder);

        if (curHatLeft && !prevHatLeft)
            euler.y -= RotationRatchet;

        prevHatLeft = curHatLeft;

        bool curHatRight = OVRInput.Get(OVRInput.Button.SecondaryShoulder);

        if (curHatRight && !prevHatRight)
            euler.y += RotationRatchet;

        prevHatRight = curHatRight;

        euler.y += buttonRotation;
        buttonRotation = 0f;


#if !UNITY_ANDROID || UNITY_EDITOR
        if (!SkipMouseRotation)
            euler.y += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * rotateInfluence * 3.25f;
#endif

        if (SnapRotation)
        {

            if (OVRInput.Get(OVRInput.Button.SecondaryThumbstickLeft))
            {
                if (ReadyToSnapTurn)
                {
                    euler.y -= RotationRatchet;
                    ReadyToSnapTurn = false;
                }
            }
            else if (OVRInput.Get(OVRInput.Button.SecondaryThumbstickRight))
            {
                if (ReadyToSnapTurn)
                {
                    euler.y += RotationRatchet;
                    ReadyToSnapTurn = false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ReadyToSnapTurn = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Vector2 secondaryAxis = OVRInput.Get(OVRInput.Axis2D.SecondaryThumbstick);
            euler.y += secondaryAxis.x * rotateInfluence;
        }

        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(euler);
    }
}


/// <summary>
/// Invoked by OVRCameraRig's UpdatedAnchors callback. Allows the Hmd rotation to update the facing direction of the player.
/// </summary>
public void UpdateTransform(OVRCameraRig rig)
{
    Transform root = CameraRig.trackingSpace;
    Transform centerEye = CameraRig.centerEyeAnchor;

    if (HmdRotatesY && !Teleported)
    {
        Vector3 prevPos = root.position;
        Quaternion prevRot = root.rotation;

        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0.0f, centerEye.rotation.eulerAngles.y, 0.0f);

        root.position = prevPos;
        root.rotation = prevRot;
    }

    UpdateController();
    if (TransformUpdated != null)
    {
        TransformUpdated(root);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Jump! Must be enabled manually.
/// </summary>
public bool Jump()
{
    if (!Controller.isGrounded)
        return false;

    MoveThrottle += new Vector3(0, transform.lossyScale.y * JumpForce, 0);

    return true;
}

/// <summary>
/// Stop this instance.
/// </summary>
public void Stop()
{
    Controller.Move(Vector3.zero);
    MoveThrottle = Vector3.zero;
    FallSpeed = 0.0f;
}

/// <summary>
/// Gets the move scale multiplier.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="moveScaleMultiplier">Move scale multiplier.</param>
public void GetMoveScaleMultiplier(ref float moveScaleMultiplier)
{
    moveScaleMultiplier = MoveScaleMultiplier;
}

/// <summary>
/// Sets the move scale multiplier.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="moveScaleMultiplier">Move scale multiplier.</param>
public void SetMoveScaleMultiplier(float moveScaleMultiplier)
{
    MoveScaleMultiplier = moveScaleMultiplier;
}

/// <summary>
/// Gets the rotation scale multiplier.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="rotationScaleMultiplier">Rotation scale multiplier.</param>
public void GetRotationScaleMultiplier(ref float rotationScaleMultiplier)
{
    rotationScaleMultiplier = RotationScaleMultiplier;
}

/// <summary>
/// Sets the rotation scale multiplier.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="rotationScaleMultiplier">Rotation scale multiplier.</param>
public void SetRotationScaleMultiplier(float rotationScaleMultiplier)
{
    RotationScaleMultiplier = rotationScaleMultiplier;
}

/// <summary>
/// Gets the allow mouse rotation.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="skipMouseRotation">Allow mouse rotation.</param>
public void GetSkipMouseRotation(ref bool skipMouseRotation)
{
    skipMouseRotation = SkipMouseRotation;
}

/// <summary>
/// Sets the allow mouse rotation.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="skipMouseRotation">If set to <c>true</c> allow mouse rotation.</param>
public void SetSkipMouseRotation(bool skipMouseRotation)
{
    SkipMouseRotation = skipMouseRotation;
}

/// <summary>
/// Gets the halt update movement.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="haltUpdateMovement">Halt update movement.</param>
public void GetHaltUpdateMovement(ref bool haltUpdateMovement)
{
    haltUpdateMovement = HaltUpdateMovement;
}

/// <summary>
/// Sets the halt update movement.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="haltUpdateMovement">If set to <c>true</c> halt update movement.</param>
public void SetHaltUpdateMovement(bool haltUpdateMovement)
{
    HaltUpdateMovement = haltUpdateMovement;
}

/// <summary>
/// Resets the player look rotation when the device orientation is reset.
/// </summary>
public void ResetOrientation()
{
    if (HmdResetsY && !HmdRotatesY)
    {
        Vector3 euler = transform.rotation.eulerAngles;
        euler.y = InitialYRotation;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(euler);
    }
}
```

}